# Looking for a direct proof for an identity in even-order groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of even order. I am interested in the following identity:
$$\large{(x_1^2 x_2^2 \cdots x_n^2)^{\frac{|G|}{2}} = 1}$$
For arbitrary $x_i \in G$.

I do know a certain proof, but it is very non-direct. I wonder whether this simple-looking identity can be proved without appeal to permutation groups.

The proof I know can be found implicitly [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Morton79.pdf). The idea is this: by composing the natural map $G \to S_G$ (Cayley Theorem) with $S_G \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ (signature of a permutation), you get a homom' from $G$ to $\{ \pm 1 \}$, which can be given explicitly by $f(x)=(-1)^{\frac{|G|}{\text{ord}(x)}}$ (there's a small computation I left out). The kernel is a subgroup consisting of elements whose order divides $\frac{|G|}{2}$. As it contains the squares, it also contains products of squares.

Comment: I like the proof you already know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an alternative proof (perhaps worse).

Assume that $G$ has order $2^nm$, with $m$ odd.  If $G$ has an element $x$ of order not dividing $2^{n-1}m$, then $x^m$ must have order $2^n$, thus $G$ has a cyclic $2$-Sylow subgroup.  It is classic that a finite groupe with a cyclic $2$-Sylow subgroup has a normal $2$-complement, so $G$ has a normal subgroup $M$ of order $m$.  $G/M$ is a $2$-group, so $(G/M)^2=G^2M/M <G/M$.  Therefore $G^2<G$, and clearly $G/G^2$ is (abelian) of exponent $2$, it follows that the order of $G^2$ divides $|G|/2$.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to prove that a group with a cyclic Sylow 2-subgroup has a normal 2-complement is to observe that the element of order $2^n$ maps onto an odd permutation in the regular permutation representation, but then your proof starts looking very similar to the original one!

Comment: You are right, I was not aware about this, thank you.

Comment: Thank you, this was the kind of proof I was looking far. I'm going to delve into p-complement subgroups, I wasn't aware of that interesting notion.